# How validate a property depending on the old value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a TaskState model, it contains an Enum property "TaskState"

```
public enum State { New, Done, Cancel }
```

If "TaskState" is "Cancel" or "Done" then this property cannot be changed.

During model validation, the value has already been changed, I can get the old value in the controller, but I don’t want to remove the business logic from the model.

I have already tried to make the "OldTaskState" property, but it can also be initialized with a POST request.

Tried doing validation in the Validate method of the IValidatableObject interface, but there is no old value there either.

Comment: Hi! So you have model, that comes from FE. In your controller you are doing validation. You are checking State, if it is "New" then you are doing save of changes. Problem - you don't know what is previous state?

Comment: @demo, Hi!
Not really
I want to do a check for a status change in the model code, not in the controller
The problem is that in the model I cannot get the old value of the property
You have to do this:

var task = await _context.Tasks.FirstOrDefaultAsync (t => t .TaskId == id);

if (task.State != New) {ModelState.AddModelError ("", "Error change!");}

Comment: How are you  getting that model? If you just create/init it... It is in New state... if you are getting it from db, then why you cannot get State also?

Comment: There is a method in the controller called upon POST request
[HttpPost]
public async Task <IActionResult> Edit (int id, TaskEditModel taskedit)
{
}

Comment: ok, so in TaskEditModel state isn't present? if so, then just as you are currently doing `var task = await _context.Tasks.FirstOrDefaultAsync (t => t .TaskId == id); if (task.State != New)...`

Comment: There are no problems with getting the state from the database in this method, the problem is that this happens in the controller and not in the model (and this is business logic)

Comment: Then do that check in business logic (in some service), not in controller... just return exception, some flag or whatever you like to know that model cannot be changed...